# C# System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument to PDF Recommendation?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

We are developing a C# Application that supports printing multiple views and we would like to add printing to PDF.  This application has several 3rd party controls that handle the printing on their own so adding something like SharpPDf will not work for us we don't believe.

Either we need a 3rd party component that takes a Print document as source and produces a PDF from that, or we need a good 3rd party print driver.

I was surprised that Adobe does not offer a Distributable version of the PDF printer they bundle with Acrobat as that would be ideal.  Anyone have recommendations as to what is the best path for us on this?

Thanks in Advance,

Jeff

**UPDATE:**  So after all the suggestions and a ton of research here is what I ended up doing.  We are buying a license to Novapdf sdk for our product (http://www.novapdf.com/en/pdf-sdk.html).  I looked at over 15 different products and we went with nova because of the ease of which we could implement this in our code and the cost was right ([$899 for novaPDF SDK Single Application v7](http://www.novapdf.com/en/buy-now.html).)  The code could not have been simpler and you can start developing before you actually have the license.  Thanks again to everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a PDF printer, you can use PDF Creator, that it's free:

http://www.pdfcreator.com/

However, i'm using SharpPDF and works fine.

Comment: I thought about getting the SharpPDF printer to work, but the amount of work I think I would have to do is to great.  Because of the 3rd party control just expose a PrintDocument I am assuming we would have to create some kind of a PrintDocument to PDFDocument conversion.  Are you guys using 3rd party controls?

Comment: Jeff, i'm using iTextSharp (wrapper of sharppdf), and is very easy, for example: Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 10, 20); PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("temp.pdf", FileMode.Create)); and with simple sentences create a pdf.

Comment: Thanks Gaberiel, I will see if we can do it this way.  I would be nice to not have the user install a print driver just to support PDF.  BTW, thanks for the code, that make it a lot clearer for me.

Comment: Hey Gaberiel, I dont see a PdfWriter class in SharpPDF, is this code from SharpPDF or a different project?

Comment: I was looking in SharpPDF and not iTextSharp, I found the PdfWriter, but it takes a iTextDoc and not a  System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument, is there a conversion I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The best free tool I found is ITextSharp. It's very easy to use, and has a lot of examples online.

You can find it information at http://itextsharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

we are using Billzip http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php.  There is also a COM interface to define how you want the output file handled.  Here is the COM object info http://www.biopdf.com/guide/.